# Filter strings which doesn't includes strings from other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filtering

I want to filter an array of urls by excluding ones that contain any substrings that are in a blacklist array.

```
const urls = [
'http://example.com/people/chuck', 
'http://example.com/goats/sam', 
'http://example.com/goats/billy', 
'http://example.com/goats/linda', 
'http://example.com/cows/mary', 
'http://example.com/cows/betty', 
'http://example.com/people/betty']

const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats']

let cleanUrls = [];
```

I can do this with for-loops but I want to find a clean/concise way using filter and/or reduce.

If I didn't need to loop over x number of blacklist items:

```
cleanUrls = urls.filter( url => !url.includes(blacklist[0]) )                  
                .filter( url => !url.includes(blacklist[1]) )
```

I also don't want to just iterate through the blacklist with a forEach or map because I want to immediately stop if a particular url matches any blacklist entry.

Plain JS please.  Thank you. :)

Comment: `urls.some(url => blacklist.includes(url))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `filter()` like this:

```
const cleanUrls = urls.filter(u => blacklist.every(s => !u.includes(s)));
```

Or

```
const cleanUrls = urls.filter(u => !blacklist.some(s => u.includes(s)));
```

**Description:**

- `.includes()` will check the existence of a sub-string withing another string.
- `.every()` will check whether none of the strings of `blacklist` array exists in a particular URL.
- `.some()` will check whether any of the string of `blacklist` array exists in a particular URL.
- `.filter()` will select only those URL's which will pass the test.

**Demo:**

```js
const urls = [
  'http://example.com/people/chuck', 
  'http://example.com/goats/sam', 
  'http://example.com/goats/billy', 
  'http://example.com/goats/linda', 
  'http://example.com/cows/mary', 
  'http://example.com/cows/betty', 
  'http://example.com/people/betty'
];

const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats'];

const cleanUrls = urls.filter(u => blacklist.every(s => !u.includes(s)));

console.log(cleanUrls);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: I think you mean `some` not `every`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, I just thought `some` but mistakenly wrote another.

Comment: **To Downvoter:** May I know the reason of your downvote?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen By the way, `every()` will work too and it seems more appropriate as compared to `some()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter()`, `some()` and `includes()` methods.

```js
const urls = ['http://example.com/people/chuck', 'http://example.com/goats/sam', 'http://example.com/goats/billy', 'http://example.com/goats/linda', 'http://example.com/cows/mary', 'http://example.com/cows/betty', 'http://example.com/people/betty'];
const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats']

const result = urls.filter(url => !blacklist.some(e => url.includes(e)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easuer to turn the blacklist i to a Regex:

```
 const block = new RegExp(blacklist.join("|"));
```

Them its as simple as:

```
 cleanUrls = urls.filter(url => !url.match(block));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach & indexOf to check if the element from second array is present in the url

```js
const urls = [
  'http://example.com/people/chuck',
  'http://example.com/goats/sam',
  'http://example.com/goats/billy',
  'http://example.com/goats/linda',
  'http://example.com/cows/mary',
  'http://example.com/cows/betty',
  'http://example.com/people/betty'
]

const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats'];

var newArray = [];
blacklist.forEach(function(item) {
  if (newArray.length === 0) {
    newArray = urls.filter(function(items) {
      return (items.indexOf(item) === -1)

    })

  } else {
    newArray = newArray.filter(function(items) {
      return (items.indexOf(item) === -1)
    })
  }
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't want to just iterate through the blacklist with a forEach
>   or map because I want to immediately stop if a particular url matches
>   any blacklist entry.

The function stop searching if an element from the blacklist appears.

Recursive way to solve this problem:

```js
const urls = [
'http://example.com/people/chuck', 
'http://example.com/goats/sam', 
'http://example.com/goats/billy', 
'http://example.com/goats/linda', 
'http://example.com/cows/mary', 
'http://example.com/cows/betty', 
'http://example.com/people/betty']

const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats']

function filter([url, ...urls] =[], blackList=[], filteredUrls =[] ){
 return !url || blacklist.some(el => url.includes(el)) 
        ? filteredUrls 
        : filter(urls, blackList, [...filteredUrls, url])
}

console.log(filter(urls, blacklist));
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question. Providing two different scenarios.

```js
const urls = [
  'http://example.com/people/chuck',
  'http://example.com/goats/billy',
  'http://example.com/aagoatsss/billyyy',
  'http://example.com/people/betty'
]

const blacklist = ['cows', 'goats']

//1st approach. It will also block 'http://example.com/aagoatsss/billyyy'
let cleanUrls1 = urls.filter(
  url => blacklist.find(
    blockWord => url.indexOf(blockWord) != -1 //Url contains Block Word
  ) === undefined //url donot contain any block word.
)

console.log(cleanUrls1)

//2nd approach. It will pass 'http://example.com/aagoatsss/billyyy'

let cleanUrls2 = urls.filter(
  url => blacklist.find(
    blockWord => url.split('/').indexOf(blockWord) != -1 //Url contains Block Word
  ) === undefined //url donot contain any block word.
)
console.log(cleanUrls2)
```